# How to attach a file to a response in REST call node js

Tags: node.js

I have a file in my local drive (say test.txt) and I am trying to attach this file in a response to a REST service. I have tried resp.writeHead, and rest.attachment('./test.txt'); etc. I am sure I am missing something here. I am getting status 200 in my response on Poster window but not getting the file. Can any one help where I am missing?

```
    app.get('/getFile', function (req, resp) {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + '/MyDisk/test5.txt');
    filestream = fs.createReadStream('/MyDisk/test5.txt');
    filestream.pipe(resp);
      resp.status(200);
      resp.end();
    });
```

Comment: why negative votes for this post?

Comment: Ok. I see the problem now. I had to comment out resp.end(); to see the response successfully. The file content is being displayed on the response Poster window. So this is the only way you get the file back, or is there anyway you actually get file as an attachment?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this before sending out the response:

```
      var filename = "test5.txt";
      resp.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
      resp.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
```

Content Disposition Header lets the user save the file to their computer and then decide how to use it, instead of the browser trying to use the file.

Although you are adding the Content Disposition Header, you are adding it to a different object. Make sure you add the headers to the `resp` object and not the `res` object.